# Hide / Cap / Trim Table Width 100% - Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have been trying to find a method of being able to sort and resize a table and found the Tablesorter jquery plugin (mottie folk).

It seems to do everything I want it to do except when the text to one line

```
style="text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;"
```

then it goes off the page. The table is to 100% width and I don't want to go over that.

Is their a way to stop the content from causing the page to go over 100%

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

        <!--http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.5/css/theme.blue.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.5/js/widgets/widget-resizable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.5/js/widgets/widget-storage.min.js"></script>


    <style id="css">th.tablesorter-header.resizable-false {
    background-color: #e6bf99;
}
/* ensure box-sizing is set to content-box, if using jQuery versions older than 1.8;
 this page is using jQuery 1.4 */
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
</style>

<script id="js">$(function() {

    $('.full-width-table').tablesorter({
        theme : 'blue',
        // initialize zebra striping and resizable widgets on the table
        widgets: [ 'zebra', 'resizable', 'stickyHeaders' ],
        widgetOptions: {
            resizable: false,
            // These are the default column widths which are used when the table is
            // initialized or resizing is reset; note that the "Age" column is not
            // resizable, but the width can still be set to 40px here
            resizable_widths : [ '10%', '10%', '40px', '10%', '100px' ]
        }
    });

});</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">

    <div id="demo">

<table class="full-width-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th class="resizable-false">Age</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Peter</td><td>Parker</td><td>28</td><td>$9.99</td><td>20%</td><td>Jul 6, 2006 8:14 AM</td></tr>
        <tr><td>John</td><td>Hood</td><td>33</td><td>$19.99</td><td>25%</td><td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Clark</td><td>Kent</td><td>18</td><td>$15.89</td><td>44%</td><td>Jan 12, 2003 11:14 AM</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bruce</td><td>Almighty</td><td>45</td><td>$153.19</td><td>44%</td><td>Jan 18, 2001 9:12 AM</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Bruce</td><td>Evans</td><td>22</td><td>$13.19</td><td>11%</td><td style="text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">Jan 18, 2007 9:12 AMffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggfff</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted with thanks to Rob G over on GitHub.

Two things need modifying:

Add overflow:hidden; to the table cell.
Add table-layout:fixed; to the table.

https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1175#issuecomment-193988250

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to slove this problem is to change the values in the table. (except: building the table with divs or redesigning the table cells)
If you add `&shy;` to your string it tells the browser where it can break the string into the new line.
The browser can not break a string without whitespaces oder something like "-".

Comment: I have dynamic content from a database populating the table so I'm unable to modify the content. Are their any ways to recreate a resize able and sortable table with divs?

Comment: It is more or less a long way and if it will solve the issues is not sure. If the string has more width than the whole page, you have to tell the browser where to add the break. (maybe read the string via JavaScript, split it, add &shy;, glue it and put it back in the table)